# Return list of all containerIDs in kubernetes pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I would like to get a list of all container IDs from long running containers in a kubernetes pod. I'm working on creating a simple script that will `docker commit` any / all changes made to the images for further testing.

I've been experimenting with something like this `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o jsonpath="{.items[*].spec.containers[*].containerid}"` to no avail. Gratitude in advance for any help / perspective.

Comment: `docker commit` is rarely a best practice; you're also not guaranteed that the Kubernetes nodes will be running Docker at all, or that you'll be able to log into the nodes, or that the multiple replicas of your Deployments will have consistent sets of changes that can be merged.  Can you store data outside the container filesystem, maybe in a database, or manage changes to your application via a source control system and CI/CD pipeline?

Comment: My intention here is to provide a solution to an edge-case that is not in accordance with best practices - essentially  I'm trying to get a diff between the base container images and the containers themselves. Developers at times `exec` into the pods at make modifications to the containers, including manually updating and modifying packages. While this violates the contract of immutability, being able to get a delta between base image and changes made will allow me to do perform adhoc audits to the package manifests on the images. Do you have any suggestions @DavidMaze?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this way?

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o jsonpath='{range .items[*].status.initContainerStatuses[*]}{.containerID}{"\n"}{end}' | cut -d/ -f3
```

Comment: Thanks for jumping in @Summerborn Storm - no dice :(

Comment: Made a slight modification to Summerborn's solution: 
`kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o jsonpath='{range .items[*].status.containerStatuses[*]}{.containerID}{"\n"}{end}' | cut -d/ -f31` works!